# Problem with adding Bearer Token to header in Swift (HTTP POST call)

Tags: swift, http, post, cookies, swift4

I am trying to make an HTTP POST call to to an API.

I entered these exact parameters in Postman and got data back. There seems to be problem with this code. My bet is the problem comes from not adding the token correctly, because I made a previous POST call successfully with a similar code but no token.

```
       let parameters = ["ne_lat": "52.6", "ne_lng": "13.5", "sw_lat": "52.4", "sw_lng": "13.3", "user_latitude": "52.5311", "user_longitude": "13.3849", "zoom": "16"]

        //create the url with URL
        let url = URL(string: "https://web-production.lime.bike/api/rider/v1/views/map")! //change the url

        //create the session object
        let session = URLSession.shared

        //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET" //set http method as GET

        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        request.addValue("Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKdbnwjnOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX3Rva2VuIjoiVjZFUHSBDRVJEMyIsImxvZ2luX2NvdW50Ijo1fQ.5YP4tcLSAINDoR-txdDsYCh_k_5aRt4cIu8DvTa00GU", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")

        //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                //create json object from data
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                    print(json)
                    // handle json...
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
```

[API documentation for this call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3ocQ.png)

Link to the documentation: https://github.com/ubahnverleih/WoBike/blob/master/Lime.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Alamofire token handling, and I solved with String concat.

Try this:

```swift
 request.addValue("{\"token\":\" eyJ0eXAiOiJKdbnwjnOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX3Rva2VuIjoiVjZFUHSBDRVJEMyIsImxvZ2luX2NvdW50Ijo1fQ.5YP4tcLSAINDoR-txdDsYCh_k_5aRt4cIu8DvTa00GU\"}", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
```